# finite group homology: $nH_k(G;M)=0$ for $n=|G|$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, homological-algebra

Let $G$ be a finite group. Is there a simple proof (if any) that the order of $G$ annihilates the Eilenberg-MacLane homology $H_k(G;M)$ for all $k\geq1$?

A simple proof of the statement for cohomology can be found in Grillet, *Abstract Algebra*, 12.9.2.

Comment: If "Eilenberg-MacLane homology" is standard group homology (I don't know the former term), then this should follow from Proposition 1.8.22 in Sharifi's "An introduction to group cohomology" ( http://math.arizona.edu/~sharifi/groupcoh.pdf ).

Comment: Yes, this is just the ordinary group (co)homology. Hmm, your answer uses tools. I was thinking of a direct proof: if $z=\sum_{t\in G^n}r_t[t]\in Ker\partial_n$, then $\partial_{n+1}\sum_{g\in G}\sum_{t\in G^n}r_t[t,g]=|G|z+?$ or something like that.

Comment: Are you familiar with transfer maps? There's an in-depth explanation of them, in five different (equivalent) settings, in section III.9 of Brown's _Cohomology of Groups_.

Comment: Weibel, page 180, Theorem 6.5.8.